# What is the verse in this image?

Tags: verses

https://images.app.goo.gl/mKJjU8wceu9D2pbv8

> No soul can ever die without Allah’s Will at the destined time. Those who desire worldly gain, We will let them have it, and those who desire heavenly reward, We will grant it to them. And We will reward those who are grateful.
> Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran 3:145

This the verse "3:145".

So what is the verse in the image.

Comment: The Arabic text is verse [3:144](https://quran.com/3/144), although the english is mistranslated to preach a false belief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Muḥammad is no more than a messenger; other messengers have gone before him. If he were to die or to be killed, would you regress into disbelief? Those who do so will not harm Allah whatsoever. And Allah will reward those who are grateful*.
> Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran 3:144

> *Thus Muhammad is no more than a messenger before whom messengers have passed on. Then will it be that if he dies or gets killed youpl will turn on your heels? For whoever turns on his heels—he will not harm Allah in any way. And Allah will repay the thankful ones*.
> Fadel Soliman, Bridges’ translation 3:144

> *And Muhammad is but a messenger, there have been messengers before him. So, if he dies or is killed, would you turn back on your heels? And whoever turns back on his heels can never harm Allah at all. And Allah shall soon reward the grateful*.
> Maarif-ul-Quran 3:144

This the real verse

**Passed away is used in general sense**

Comment: Thanks for your answer